# Performance overhead for frequent (5Hz) Core Data saves

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nstimeinterval

For an iPhone app that plays audio files, I'm working on a system to track the user's progress in any episode they've listened to (eg, they listen to the first 4:35 of file1, then starts another file, and goes back to file1 and it starts at 4:35).

I've set up a Core Data model to store the metadata, but I'm wondering how aggressively I could/should cache the current location during playback.

Currently I have just stuck the save: call in a method that was previously being used to update the time labels and UISlider playhead. That method is being called by a NSTimerInterval every 0.2 seconds.

0.2 seconds is much more precision than I need to keep track of for the progress cache. The values are rounded to the nearest second anyway, so essentially 4/5 of every save is redundant.

Given, though, that this is pretty much all Core Data is doing, it's only only ever dealing with a single value for a single record at any given time, I'm wondering if it makes more sense to just do the extra, unnecessary save:'s, or to manage a second timer for doing the update less frequently.

As is, Instruments reports the Save Duration of each event as ~800, peaking around 2000. I'm not really sure how to interpret those results. Actual app performance in the simulator doesn't appear to be significantly impacted.

If this kind of save is so cheap that it makes sense to keep code complexity low (only managing a single timer), I would keep it as is, but my gut instinct is that that's a lot of operations, no matter how cheap.

Comment: Can you skip the save altogether, and just record the current position in audio stream when the user moves to another stream?

Comment: I could, but I'm a little worried that even if I do the legwork to make sure it always gets saved before the app quits, if it crashes or the (eg) the connection goes down and access to the file is lost, or some other edge case, it wouldn't get updated. I would never want to lose more than ~10 seconds of progress, so I'd at least need to make a 10 second timer; but I wouldn't want to *only* have a precision of 10 seconds.

Comment: I see - how much data are you saving? You only really need to write a float every <10 seconds.

Comment: I'm only saving that single NSNumber attribute on one document. 10 seconds is the max I'd ever want to go without explicitly doing a save, so I'm trying to figure out what kind of performance difference, if any, there is between doing it every 5 seconds, every 1 second, five times per second, etc. If I could piggyback this operation on the current timer that already exists I can keep my code pretty lean. If I need to start managing a second timer things get a little complicated because of the way the audio player library I'm using works underneath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't see as much of a difference in performance as you may see in battery consumption.

Writing to disk with flash storage in an iOS device is much faster than writing to a spinning plate HDD on a computer.  Also, a write to a HDD does not cost much electricity compared to just keeping the plated spinning anyway.  However, writing to the flash storage takes more power relative to a read or just leaving the flash alone.

In other words, the power consumption for a write on an iOS device it not negligible.  If you can get away with 4hz, that could easily result in a notable improvement in batter consumption for your app.

Comment: Can you give some sense of how much extra battery? I realize doing the same thing three times as often will use three times as much power. But let's say listening to an hour long podcast, saving at 1Hz, takes up 2% of the battery (including all other phone operations). Would going the 3Hz use 6% of the batter? Or like 2.1%?

Comment: Well, that's pretty tough to say.  It would depend on which specific model of device, how many seconds your app performs these writes, and what other actions are being performed at the time.  Instruments does have a tool that simulates looking at batter consumption.  Check here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Built-InInstruments/Built-InInstruments.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH6-SW63

Comment: Correction: the tool mentioned in the comment above helps you to measure the battery consumption on an actual device.